# Rails - SendGrid gem is not adding unique arguments

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, sendgrid

I am using this [SendGrid](https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid) gem, which works fine and it sends emails through SendGrid. Unfortunately the `sendgrid_unique_args` and `sendgrid_category` functions are not defined inside my mailer. What library should I include to make them available?

Thanks

Comment: The https://github.com/stephenb/sendgrid readme file failed to mention including SendGrid library. `include SendGrid` in the mailer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The README doesn't mention this, but if you take a look at the tests, you actually need to include the SendGrid library in your mailer.  For example:

```
class MyMailerClass < ActionMailer::Base
  include SendGrid
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Yeah I noticed, it seems the newer version will automatically include SendGrid. The comment on the last commit `Add railtie to automatically include SendGrid in ActionMailer`.